# Transistor Junction voltage

Tags: transistors

If we take a Common Base configured transistor in to consideration..Will the collector base junction break if we apply high voltage of like 7volts?if it breaks then does it give large current

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the transistor. Look in its datasheet for a specification called "V<sub>cbo</sub>", which stands for "maximum **V**oltage, **c**ollector-to-**b**ase, emitter **o**pen".

If you exceed this value, the transistor may or may not be damaged, depending on how much current you allow to flow — i.e., how much power the transistor disspates while the current is flowing. Generally speaking, it is the temperature rise from this heating that produces permanent damage.

Sometimes, a transistor is deliberately operated in reverse-breakdown mode, although the more heavily-doped base-emiiter junction is usually used. For example, a transistor operating in its Zener breakdown region makes a pretty good wideband noise source for some applications.

Comment: Some RF/highfreq MicroT devices from Motorola, with 5GHz Ftau, had only 5 volts Vce rating.